# understanding $\int_{F} E[X|\mathcal{F}]dP=\int_F E[X]dP$ in the definition of conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

In the definition of conditional expectation, we require $\int_{F} E[X|\mathcal{F}]dP=\int_F X dP$ for all $F \in \mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is a sub $\sigma$-algebra, and this condition implies $E[E[X|\mathcal{F}]]=E[X]$. What can go wrong if we alternatively define a conditional expectation to be a measurable random variable that satisfies $E[E[X|\mathcal{F}]]=E[X]$? Existence is definitely still true, so I think it is uniqueness is what we need to worry about, but I am having trouble thinking of a $\mathcal{F}$-measurable random variable satisfying $E[E[X|\mathcal{F}]]=E[X]$ that is not the conditional expectation using the correct definition.

Comment: Well, then $\mathbb{E}[X]$ would be a candidate that satisfy the condition but that is not the conditional expectation, more generally any conditional expectation of $X$ on any sub $\sigma$-algebra would work.

Comment: The requirement is that the left hand side equals $\int_F X dP$, the expression $\int_F E[X] dP$ is just $E[X]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let$(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$ be a probability space and $\mathcal F$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal A$. If $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ is a random variable, the conditional expectation $E[X|\mathcal F]$ is the "best $\mathcal F$-measurable function that approximates $X$" in the sense of the integral, that is, for all $F\in \mathcal F$ we have $$\int_FE[X|\mathcal F] dP = \int_F X dP$$
This idea is what my teacher uses to provide myself with an intuitive idea when I studied probability. It is supported by some examples: if you take $\mathcal F=\{\varnothing, \Omega\}$, then $E[X|\mathcal F]$ is a number (because every function that is $\{\varnothing, \Omega\}$-measurable must be a constant), and that constant is precisely $E[X]$. Thus we recover the idea that "the best number that can be used to summarize certain data is the mean".

- It is not difficult to think of a random variable $Y$ so that $E[Y]=E[X]$ but $Y \neq E[X|\mathcal F]$. For example, take $Y=E[X]$.
  To be more specific, let $$X:([0,1], \mathcal B, m) \to ([0,1], \mathcal B) \quad , \quad X(x)=x$$
  where $\mathcal B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Pick $\mathcal F$ any sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal B$. If $Y=\frac12$, then $E[X]=E[Y]$ but $\int_F Y dP \neq \int_F X dP$ for any interval $F=[0,a]$, $0<a<1$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: sorry for being d*ck, but "the best number that can be used to summarize certain data is the mean" statement is not true in general. you have to specify in which sense, i.e. what you mean saying _the best_.

Comment: yes, it is true. I just pretended to use that as an example without being extremely technical. The median, for example, does not fit well in this context of integrals.